# Run mocha tests in test environment?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I can't seem to tell mocha to run my test suite in the test environment.

**app.js**

```
app.configure('test', function(){
  app.set('port', 3002);
});
```

**test/some-test.coffee**

```
app = require('../../app')

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'

describe 'some test', ->
  it 'should pass', ->
```

Since I'm requiring app, when I run the tests I expect to see

`Express server listening on port 3002`

and instead I see

`Express server listening on port 3000`

Setting a different port number in a development configuration block in app.js yields

`Express server listening on port [whatever port I set in development block in app.js]`

I cannot get my tests to run in a test environment. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. You need to define NODE_ENV before you require `app.js`:

   ```
   process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'

   app = require('../../app')

   describe 'some test', ->
     it 'should pass', ->
   ```
2. You can't change listening port by `app.set`. There is only one way to set port - pass it into `listen` method. You can do something like this:

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.send('hello world');
   });

   var port = 3000;

   app.configure('test', function(){
     port = 3002;
   });

   app.listen(port);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, point #1 was the solution. However, I can use `app.set('port', [port])` in the environment configurations and pass `app.get('port')` to the `listen` function. In fact, express (3.0.0rc3) does this when generating app.js. Thanks again!

Comment: As a recommendation for anyone else who comes across this, I *highly* suggest that you set process.env as early as possible. In my case I was using mocha & chai with Apollo Server (lambda) and this was still applicable. Thanks @Vadim Baryshev!

Answer (score 27):

I would take a different approach from Vadim. Using Vadim's example you could instead load environment settings based on your `process.env.NODE_ENV` value. I know there is another step in my approach, but it is cleaner, extensible, and will prevent the addition of test conditionals in your logic.

This approach uses [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.org/package/dotenv), then defining both a `default` and a `test` environment file in the root of the application. These files will allow you to reconfigure properties within your application without changing your JavaScript.

1. Add dotenv as a `dependency` in your `package.json` file then install the new packages into your `node_modules` folder:

   **package.json**

   ```
   {
     ...
     "dependencies": {
       ...
       "dotenv": "0.2.8"
     }
   }
   ```

   **command line**

   ```
   $ npm install
   ```
2. Change your `app.js` so that the port is using an environment value set from the loaded .env file.

   ```
   // Load .env files from root based on the NODE_ENV value
   require('dotenv').load();

   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.send('hello world');
   });

   var port = process.env.port || 3000;
   -----------^

   app.listen(port);
   ```
3. Create two files in your folder root, `.env` & `.env.test`, just add the one line below. These files have simple key value pairs on each line which can be accessed when prefixed with `process.env.`.

   **.env**

   ```
   port=3000
   ```

   **.env.test**

   ```
   port=3002
   ```
4. From the command line or when you call your tests I would set `NODE_ENV`:

   ```
   $ NODE_ENV=test mocha <TEST_FOLDER>/*.js
     ---------^
   ```

When you run the application in all other cases without setting `NODE_ENV`, the values in the default `.env` file will be loaded into `process.env`.

Comment: For step 4 I ended up just having the production .env in the application root folder and another .env in my test/ folder. Then in my test scripts I explicitly tell dotenv to use the test/.env file using the dotenv custom location path method.

Comment: FYI - as of dotenv 1.0 they yanked the ability to load name .env files (.env.test, .env.produduction, ...) using the value from NODE_ENV.

Comment: It's not a problem, for latest version do something like require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`, silent: true });

Comment: thanks for this solution, I was able to run my mocha tests with my .env: 
1) npm install dotenv --save
2) require('dotenv').config();

This code will automatically load the .env

Answer (score 3):

`npm install --save-dev cross-env`

#### add `cross-env NODE_ENV=test` on script block of package.json

`package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "test-unit": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha src/**/*.unittest.js --colors",
  },
```

Comment: Ensure to install cross-env as a dev depency first `npm install --save-dev cross-env`